How do I increase the resources allocated to individual docker container instances running in Colima?
I see that I can increase the resources of the Colima VM, but the docker containers are executed with the default configuration:
$: colima start --cpu 10 --memory 20 --disk 50
$: colima list

PROFILE    STATUS     ARCH       CPUS    MEMORY    DISK     RUNTIME    ADDRESS
default    Running    aarch64    10      20GiB     50GiB    docker     
docker     Running    aarch64    2       2GiB      60GiB    docker

Colima has 20 GB of memory, but docker is running with 2 CPUs and 2GiB. But when I build an image, I have a ceiling:
CONTAINER ID   NAME             CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O         PIDS
5410ba766514   container-name   9.74%     1.415GiB / 1.914GiB   73.91%    17.8kB / 11.9kB   82.8MB / 28.7kB   479

How do I increase memory and core ct for individual docker instances?

More details, because I think this may be a "what do I configure" question. I am running:

colima on macOS
kubernetes on colima
a kubernetes cluster specified by kind
a kubeflow deployment installed by kustomize on the kind cluster
docker installed via brew under colima

And I cannot use Docker Desktop for org reasons.

@ Chris If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for the community or upvote if the answer has some useful information.

@DharaniDharGolladasari colima got itself into a bad state where it was incompletely set to the new resource allocation.  Somehow, I had to invalidate some cache (presuming) by cycling the power, deleting colima, and so on. Eventually, it started working.

You can change the individual docker container instance resources using docker cli commands. Here are the commands:
$ docker run  -d --cpus=2 --memory=4g <image name>

InCase if you want to update the existing docker container resources then use the following commands:

First find the docker container ID using the following command
$ docker ps


Now use the container ID to update the container configurations
$ docker update --cpus =10 --memory=10g <contianer-ID>



Refer to this official docker update document for more information.

It turned out I needed to cycle the machine, destroy colima, and other things until I invalidated some cache. Then it started working.
